# Angular JS navigate with $location

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with navigating between web pages using Angular JS. First web page is index.html, next main.html and also exists a myscript.js file and style.css (but the last is irrelevant in this case).
I want to navigate from index.html to main.html by pressing a button, furthermore there are 2 variables to pass from index.html to main.html and I have to load the next web page with ui-router method or with $location variable in the actual window, as replacing index.html but not with traditional method.
How can I do this?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: angular is typically run in one html file page. Your question doesn't make much sense within the context of angular basic concepts. Are main.html and index.html just templates or full server side page loads? Either way your question needs lots of clarification

Comment: What code do you have? You can change location by using `$location.path('yourURL');`. You can pass variables by sharing `$scope` variables.

Comment: I have only 2 web pages, not special things, program have to run only in browser without web server.
There is a form in index.html, which have a submit button and if I press this button, I want to navigate to main.html. I don't know how to define code in JS file (controller, $location), this is my main question.

Comment: save yourself the trouble and put it all in one page...that's the way angular works best. Otherwise you will need to store data in localStorage or cookies or pass it through url's

Comment: I fully agree with the others and believe you need to research how Angular works. One page does not necessarily mean one HTML file for all of your pages, it means you will be loading partials into a common template. Please read the angular tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using ui router  is more flexible work with states,  if you have index.html inside you should have a ui- view attribute to change view dynamically, so in your script.js file you have to configure your states, partials views and controller per state (if you want , also you may work with resolve data), and to pass data between controllers you could use services or factory.
[This tutorial could help you.](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

Comment: Thanks! I have read this tutorial, but some descriptions are not clear... that is why I ask about these things.

Comment: i read comments and if you want some authentication logic , you could use $state.go() to navigate between state.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for answers! :)
The simpliest method was to create 2 divs on the same HTML page - checking a flag value to display divs using ng-show - instead of navigating between pages.